# Issue with display:none when the container is set to display:flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container set to `display:flex;` and a `#sidebar` which has `.mainmenu` including a `.submenu` which is set to `display:none;`. The problem is that the .submenu height is added to the `#sidebar` height although it's set to `display:none;` but when I delete the `display:flex;` style the height is only added when the `.submenu` show up using jQuery `.slideToggle();`.

Comment: This would be a great place to put at JS Fiddle so we can see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Can you get a JSFiddle up and working so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the  container that has the `display:flex` to also include an `align-items:flex-start;`

the default is set to `align-items:stretch` which causes the items to stretch to meet the height of the tallest element. If this doesn't solve it then I'd recommend creating the JSFiddle so we can have a better look.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This solved my problem :)

Comment: no problem glad I could help.